# Visual Studio 2015 RC - Cant add virtual directory

Tags: visual-studio-2015, virtual-directory

I recently upgraded my machine which meant I had to install VS 2015 RC community

opened a previous project and had to recreate all my previous virtual directories only to find when I try I get the following error message:

'The operation could not be completed'

when simply selecting Add Virtual Directory, enter the name and path and press enter.

Anyone else had that or got an idea how I get round that?

Comment: I have given answer for same [here][1].

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694217/visual-studio-2015-adding-virtual-directory-not-possible


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694217/visual-studio-2015-adding-virtual-directory-not-possible

Answer (score 1):

Maybe editting your applicationhostfile will help. The virtual paths must be part of the site

```
<!--path of your site-->
<site name="[NAMEOFSITE]" id="[SITEID]">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="[PATHTOSITE]" />
    </application>
    <!-- virtual path-->
    <application path="[VIRTUAL_PATH]" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="[PHYSICAL_PATH_OF_VIRTUAL]" />
     </application>
     <bindings>
         <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:[PORTNUMBER]:localhost" />
     </bindings>
</site>
```