# Vusual Studio 2015 Doesn't load 2013 web Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2013 which contains three class library projects and 2 UI projects which works great without any issue.
Last week, I decided to install Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise so that I can use 2015 and 2013 side-by-side and then ultimately get rid of 2013 if everything is working fine in 2015.
I hit the very first roadblock when I try to load the solution in 2015 and it doesn't load two UI projects I created using Visual Studio 2013. When I right click and reload the project, I throws the following error:

> Creation of Virtual Directory http://mysite.abc.com failed with the
>   error: Cannot create the website http://mysite.abc.com. you must
>   specify localhost for the servername

Comment: Have you tried this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694217/visual-studio-2015-adding-virtual-directory-not-possible

Comment: Yes.. I already tried this thread but not helping it.