# Must Create Virtual Directory Before Each Build to Prevent Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2019

I am getting the below error every time I build my project using IIS Express:

```
"It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."
```

If I go into the Web Debug Properties and click "Create Virtual Directory" it will let me build it one time, and then it will work. However, I have to do this before building every time.

Also, when I try to publish, it errors out with the same error as well, but the above work-around doesn't resolve it.

Comment: are you using IIS express, or a full web site that that you can configure a virtual directory? How to create a virtual directory for IIS is outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694217/visual-studio-2015-adding-virtual-directory-not-possible

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this error, you can try the following methods to solve the problem:

1.restart of Visual Studio and try again.

2.Deleting the OBJ folder(\myWebApp\obj).

3.Click on the Web.config file from Solution explorer and right click "Properties" and change to "Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy".

[image]

4.Clean solution whilst your solution is configured in Debug/Release mode.